# Display updated data with ajax in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a static_pages_controller with a `home` method.

On the `home.html.erb` page I have a button:

```
<%= button_to "Refresh recommendations",  
{action: :home, reset: true},method: :get,remote: true , class: 'btn btn-success'%>
```

When a user clicks the button I want have the controller recompute a list of recommendation, this is working,
the issue I am having is updating the div containing the list of new recommendations.

static_pages_controller#home

```
def home
 puts "PARAMS #{params}"

 respond_to do |format|
   format.html{}
   format.js 
 end
end
```

From various guides and thread I've been following that I should have a `home.js.erb` and from my understanding when the ajax call is made the controller should execute home.js.erb - it currently is not executing.

I've included my `routes.rb` just incase something is messed up.

```
root "static_pages#home"
post '/spec', to: "static_pages#spec_rec"
```

When submitting the ajax request the server will outputs the following:

```
Started GET "/refresh" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-13 12:11:27 -0400
Processing by StaticPagesController#refresh as JS
Rendered static_pages/_refresh.html.erb (0.1ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes file, you should have something like

```
  get 'home/refresh', to: 'home#refresh'
```

In your home controller you should have

```
def refresh
  render partial: 'refresh'
end
```

You should make a partial _refresh in your view home folder, containing the refreshing html

In your view

```
<%= button_to "Refresh recommendations", refresh_home_path, remote: true, class: 'refresh btn btn-success', type: :html %>
```

and

```
javascript:
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('ajax:success', ".refresh", function(evt, data, status, xhr){
      $(selector for your div).html(data);
    });       
  });
```

That should do the job!

Comment: Attempting this solution I am getting the error no route matching post "/refresh". Do I need to force button_to as a get request?

Comment: You shouldn't use post /refresh, but rather the by rails created refresh_home_path, as indicated in my answer. The way it's currently suggested, is with a "get", not a "post"

Comment: The issue I'm having is the javascript is never being called-> I even changed the js just to alert(this) to test whether or not it is being called. Ill update my main post with information from the server

Comment: Found my error - I was creating the js file in the javascript directory, a terrible oversight by myself, thank you very much for your help and patience!